# Prove Weierstrass function has a pole of order 2 for all $\omega \in L$

Tags: functional-analysis

I need some help to prove Weierstrass function has a pole of order 2.

The Weierstrass function $\wp$-function of lattice $L$ is defined by
$$\wp(z) = \wp(z; L) = \frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{w \in L\setminus\{0, 0\}} \left[ \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2} + \frac{1}{\omega^2} \right]$$

I can prove $\sum_{\omega \in L\setminus\{0, 0\}} \big[ \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2} + \frac{1}{\omega^2}  \big]$ has a pole of order $2$ for all $\omega \in L$

My question:

Is that pole of $\sum_{\omega \in L\setminus\{0, 0\}} \big[ \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2} + \frac{1}{\omega^2}  \big] = \frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{w \in L\setminus\{0, 0\}} \big[ \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2} + \frac{1}{\omega^2} \big]\text{ ?}$

Comment: What is that symbol you use called?

Comment: I don't think the symbol has a name, it's just pronounced "p-function"

Comment: please don't put down vote if you don't know what the name of symbol

Comment: I have seen it spelled out, Weierstrass pe function.

Answer (score 2):

The $\dfrac{1}{z^2}$ term has a double pole precisely when $z=0$, which is the only lattice point not covered by the sum. If you put $z=0$ in the sum, then you will get something nonzero which means it has neither a pole nor a zero there.

Therefore,you can just treat the terms separately as they don't interfere with each other and the double pole at every other lattice point comes from the summation as you have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to know how to identify poles of a sum, knowing the poles of the two terms?  If there are no poles in common, that is easy.

Comment: You put this down as an ANSWER?